# How to assert page doesnt reload with Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am running a test that assures a page does not reload when a button is clicked. So far, I have not found the best way to assert on this. I initially thought to create a route and wait for the xhr request that I don't want to happen, and if it happens, to fail the test. However, there does not appear to be a way to catch an error from a cy.wait() which makes it impossible for me to pass the test once the timeout occurs. My current solution is to ensure that the href for the given element starts with "#", but that seems to have the shortcoming of someone potentially attaching an event to it that would in-fact reload the page and it would not be caught by my test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API):

In your test you will need to assert something like:

```
expect(performance.navigation.type).to.equal(performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD);
```

Comment: I used expect(performance.navigation.type).to.not.equal(TYPE_RELOAD) with setting TYPE_RELOAD to 1

Comment: This API is deprecated, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58652880/802365

Answer (score 1):

#### Using A Flag on the Window Object

In my tests, I used the method described in [Detect page reload from Cypress test](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/detect-page-reload/) by adding a new property `shouldNotReloadOnFirefox` to the `window` object, then cheking it's still present (i.e. no reload):

```
// arrange
cy.window().then((win) => (win.shouldNotReloadOnFirefox = true));

// act 
cy.whateverYouAreTesting()

// assert
cy.window().should('have.prop', 'shouldNotReloadOnFirefox');
```

#### Using Browser API

**As of 2021-05-27**

`performance.navigation` was **deprecated**.

You should use [PerformanceNavigationTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) instead and the `getEntriesByType` method:

```
expect(performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0].type).to.equal(
  'reload'
);
```